# Towers of Hanoi redux

Tags: c++, tower-of-hanoi

Inspired by Mayur Kulkarni's question this morning, I decided to post some code for the classic Towers of Hanoi problem, but this time in C++. Since this is fairly "textbook" kind of task, all suggestions are welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

class Hanoi {
    typedef std::vector<int> Tower;
    Tower a, b, c;

    void show(std::string const &label, Tower c) {
        std::cout << label;
        std::copy(c.cbegin(), c.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    void dump() {
        show("A: ", a);
        show("B: ", b);
        show("C: ", c);
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    void MoveDisc(Tower &a, Tower &b) {
        b.push_back(a.back());
        a.pop_back();
    }

    void MoveStack(Tower &a, Tower &b, Tower &c, size_t size) {
        if (size == 0)
            return;
        MoveStack(a, c, b, size - 1);
        MoveDisc(a, b);
        dump();
        MoveStack(c, b, a, size - 1);
    }
public:
    Hanoi(std::initializer_list<int> input) : a(input) { dump(); }

    void operator()() { MoveStack(a, c, b, a.size()); }
};

int main() {
    Hanoi h { 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5 };
    h();    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are just a few observations that may help you improve your code.  In all, it is quite clean and easy to read and understand.

### Use `const` where practical

The `show()` and `dump()` function don't (and shouldn't) alter the underlying object, so they should be declared `const`:

```
void show(std::string const &label, Tower c) const;
void dump() const;
```

### Use `reserve()` to prevent reallocations

The constructor can easily determine the maximum size of the vectors.  If there were much larger ones than this, one could avoid potentially costly memory reallocations by using `Tower.reserve()` within the constructor.

### Prefer flexible output

This is admittedly a very simple program, but generally it's nice to allow for printing to any `std::ostream` rather than having `std::cout` hardcoded into the class.  Perhaps it could be a constructor argument.

### Use all required `#include`s

The code makes use of `std::initializer_list` but doesn't have this line:

```
#include <initializer_list>
```

**However,** as @Morwenn points out in a comment, it's not needed to include it explicitly since `std::vector` must necessarily already include it.

Comment: I'm somewhat curious: does the fact that `std::vector` has a ctor that accepts an `initializer_list` mean that including `<vector>` necessarily declares `initializer_list`?

Comment: It's a good question. Probably so, but I'd be inclined to include it anyway because its explicitly used.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The synopsis of every container header in the latest draft has an explicit `#include <initializer_list>`, even `<array>` which doesn't even use it IIRC. So it's guaranteed that including `<vector>` also includes `<initializer_list>`.

Comment: @Morwenn: thanks for checking.  I've included that into my answer.